# How to obtain a value/element from one Java class in another Java class in the same page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I am trying to add a dynamic display for a page based on context of the first java component. I have 2 global Java classes handling logics for the same page. The first java class (details) retrieves data from a JSON and store it for display later using JSP as view. The other Java class (display text) needs to know if 1 data value (promotion) exists from the other Java and display different texts based on promotion exists or not.

Currently the 2 classes are independently created so the value promotion cannot be passed into the constructor of the second class.

Problem:
 Since the second Java class is also global, getting the entire JSON functionality from the first Java class is expensive since this component is used in every pages.
I am trying to use javascript getElementbyId by setting a id in the first jsp component and retrieve the id in the second class to display different texts. The down side is it relies on the UI html element to see whether to display the content in the second java component. Another solution I am thinking to use is servletContext to set the promotion variable in the first class, when the second class checks and see the variable exists it can display the texts. Is there any other recommendation for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

are you using spring as a background framework. This would allow the use of its dependency injection, and thus you could pass whatever values you need from the first class to the second's constructor.

This would also reduce your dependency and complexity.

Comment: The current structure of the 2 classes does not allow pass in of the parameters into the second class. I was thinking of using javascript read current page's element or using Java servlet context to set an attribute in the first class and retrieve it in the second class.

Comment: Setting the servlet context is not a good idea as it unnecessarily overloads the JVM. a better yet simple solution could be adding a getter and setter for the property on the second class, and prior to making a call to your specific method, call the setter and use the value via the getter,

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i have thought about putting a getter/setter to the second class so the first class can set it and be retrieved later. But the problem is that the 2 classes does not talk to each even though they are within the same page. They are two components that are added into a cq adobe web content management system.